# Could there be a broader interpretation for Old Testament bible hebrew word/term for Proverbs 29:18's revelation/vision/prophetic vision?

Tags: translation-philosophy, hebrew-bible, intertextuality, rabbinic-interpretation

> 29:18 Hebrew OT: Westminster Leningrad Codex בְּאֵ֣ין חָ֭זֹון
> יִפָּ֣רַֽע עָ֑ם וְשֹׁמֵ֖ר תֹּורָ֣ה אַשְׁרֵֽהוּ׃
>
> 29:19 Hebrew OT: Westminster Leningrad Codex בִּ֭דְבָרִים
> לֹא־יִוָּ֣סֶר עָ֑בֶד כִּֽי־יָ֝בִ֗ין וְאֵ֣ין מַעֲנֶֽה׃

> (Proverbs 29:18-19)  NASB1995
>
> Where there is no [a]vision, the people are unrestrained, But happy is
> he who keeps the law. 19 A slave will not be instructed by words
> alone; For though he understands, there will be no response.

> Proverbs 29:18-19
> English Standard Version
>
> 18 Where there is no prophetic vision the people cast off
> restraint,[a]
> but blessed is he who keeps the law. 19 By mere words a servant is not disciplined,
> for though he understands, he will not respond.
>
> Proverbs 29:18-19
>
> New King James Version
>
> 18 Where there is no [a]revelation, the people cast off restraint; But
> happy is he who keeps the law.
>
> 19 A servant will not be corrected by mere words; For though he
> understands, he will not respond.

> 29:18 Hebrew OT: Westminster Leningrad Codex בְּאֵ֣ין חָ֭זֹון
> יִפָּ֣רַֽע עָ֑ם וְשֹׁמֵ֖ר תֹּורָ֣ה אַשְׁרֵֽהוּ׃
>
> 29:19 Hebrew OT: Westminster Leningrad Codex בִּ֭דְבָרִים
> לֹא־יִוָּ֣סֶר עָ֑בֶד כִּֽי־יָ֝בִ֗ין וְאֵ֣ין מַעֲנֶֽה׃

I might just be nitpicking unnecessarily, but could someone please
check if the Old Testament bible Hebrew word/term for Proverbs 29:18's
revelation/vision/prophetic vision can be even more broadly
interpreted as meaning Godly Guidance, Godly Wisdom, a person's Godly
walk, etc.?

Comment: The main role of the prophets of Israel was to prove them about their wrong-doings, and bring them back to the righteous path. So when there are no prophets, and no prophetic vision, people will turn away from the law/Torah. The other verse does not seem related to the first one.

Answer (score 2):

The operative word in Prov 29:18 is חָזוֹן (chazon) whose BDB entry is listed in the appendix below.  This word occurs 35 times in the OT Hebrew.  According to Strong's lexicon, it has this meaning:

> From chazah; a sight (mentally), i.e. A dream, revelation, or oracle
> -- vision.

More helpfully, "The Complete Word Study Dictionary OT" by Baker and Carpenter defines the word as follows:

> ... a revelation by means of a vision, oracle, a divine communication.
> The primary essence of this word is not so much the vision or dream
> itself as the message conveyed.  It signifies, the direct, specific
> communication between God and people through the prophetic office (1
> Sam 3;1, 1 Chron 17:15, Ps 89:19) or the collection of such messages
> (2 Chron 32:32, Isa 1:1, Obad 1:1, Nah 1:1, Hab 2:2, 3).  Also, the
> word is used of the messages of false prophets (Jer 14:14, 23:16); a
> guiding communication from the Lord, often restricted when people are
> under judgement (Lam 2:9, Eze 7:26, Mic 3:6); and the revelation of
> future events on a grand scale (Dan 9:24, 10:14). People who disregard
> this divine communication face certain doom (Prov 29:18).

That is, the word does not mean simply "vision", but communication from God.  Thus, I believe the most helpful translation of Prov 29:18 is given by the following versions:

- NIV: Where there is no **revelation**, people cast off restraint; but blessed is the one who heeds wisdom’s instruction.
- NKJV: Where there is no **revelation**, the people cast off restraint; But happy is he who keeps the law.
- CSB: Without **revelation** people run wild, but one who follows divine instruction will be happy.
- HCSB: Without **revelation** people run wild, but one who listens to instruction will be happy.
- CEV: Without **guidance from God** law and order disappear, but God blesses everyone who obeys his Law.
- NHEB: Where there is no **revelation**, the people cast off restraint; but he who keeps the law is blessed.
- WEB: Where there is no **revelation**, the people cast off restraint; but one who keeps the law is blessed.
- GNT: A nation without **God's guidance** is a nation without order. Happy are those who keep God's law!

For what it is worth, here is my personal translation:

> Where no revelation, people cast off restraint; but happy is he who
> keeps the law/Torah.

**APPENDIX - BDB entry for חָזוֹן (chazon)**

> חָזוֺן noun masculine Daniel 8:1 vision (on formation compare LgBN
> 204) — absolute ׳ח Hosea 12:11 25t.; construct חֲזוֺן Isaiah 1:1 8t.
>
> 1. vision, as seen in the ecstatic state "" קסם Micah 3:6; "" מקסם Ezekiel 12:24; "" חלמות Daniel 1:17; "" נביא Daniel 9:24; ׳חזה ח
>    Ezekiel 12:27; Ezekiel 13:16; ׳ראה ח Daniel 8:15; ׳ראה בח Daniel 8:2
>    (twice in verse); Daniel 9:21; ׳דבּר בח Psalm 89:20; חזון נראה אל
>    Daniel 8:1 vision appeared unto; ׳מצא ח מיהוה Lamentations 2:9 find a
>    vision from Yahweh; also Ezekiel 12:22,23; Daniel 8:13,17,26; Daniel
>    10:14; Daniel 11:14.
> 2. vision, in the night חֲזוֺן לַיְלָה Isaiah 29:7.
> 3. divine communication in a vision, oracle, prophecy ׳בקשׁ ח מנביא seek a vision (prophecy) from prophet Ezekiel 7:26; "" דבר (יםׅ 1
>    Samuel 3:1; 1 Chronicles 17:15; חֲזוֺן לִבָּם יְדַבֵּ֑רוּ Jeremiah
>    23:16 a prophecy of their own hearts (minds) they speak; חֲזוֺן שֶׁקֶר
>    וְקֶסֶם אֱלִיל וְתַרְמִית לִבָּם הֵמָּה מִתְנַבְּאִים Jeremiah 14:14
>    FALSE vision and (see אֱלִיל) worthless divination & deceit of their
>    own hearts they are prophesying; ׳כתב ח write the vision Habakkuk 2:2;
>    also Hosea 12:11; Habakkuk 2:3; Proverbs 29:18; Ezekiel 7:13 (strike
>    out Co).
> 4. vision, as title of book of prophecy, ספר חזון נחוּם Nahum 1:1; ישׁעיהו ׳ח Isaiah 1:1; עבדיה ׳ח Obadiah; of other writings of prophets
>    2 Chronicles 32:32.